# Bind Column value to dynamically created button in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I m developing a WPF application where in my database there are two columns(product_id,product_name). and want to add button dynamically on basis of number of product in database table.so bind this two columns with dynamically created button because i want to perform some action on click event on basis of product_id.can you help me to how to bind this two column with button or how extend button base class to solve this issue?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: i have assign this two values to tooltip and content properties of button but i don't want to assign product_id to tooltip but i want specific property for product_id

Answer (score 0):

Please learn MVVM before writing single line of code in wpf.

For now on you can achieve what you wanted in below crude manner:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
   public ProductID{get;set;}
   public Productname{get;set;}
}
```

Code behind

```
public void Populate()
{
    IList<Product> products = LoadFromDatabase(); // Function to load database records as Product class instances.
    myListBox.ItemsSource = products;
}
```

View:

```
 <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding ProductName}"></Button>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: @SANDEEP you can start from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: but my button created dynamically from code behind.is this code useful for my issue.?

Comment: this code will generate the list of buttons according to your database records.. so you need not to create button in code behind.. you can bind properties of button defined in the datatemplate